# Unexpected top space when li element text is overflowing after ::before

Tags: html, css

I have a list component with a custom bullet defined as a before pseudoelement:

```
li:before {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: .8rem;
  height: .8rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: -2.9rem;
  background-color: #00c878;
  border-radius: .375rem;
  content: "";
}
```

It all works fine as long as the li content doesn't overflow the container. Then, the whole content just jumps down a few pixels and leaves a weird top margin between the bullet and the content.

[image]

I have recreated it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u4rp75zL/).

I have managed to make it disappear using `work-break: break-all`, but that is of course not a susteinable solution.

Any tips?

Comment: if your remove the negative margin you will see the trick, you need to consider position:absolute here for the bullet

Comment: If you don't want them to overflow then `white-space: nowrap;` could be of help here.

Comment: Please add the HTML here so we have something more to work with.  Note you can use a snippet right in the question that can replace the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing custom pseudo-elements it's better to position them absolute and relative to the `li`. See example below, this has fixed your issue:

```
li {
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: -29px;
  background-color: #00c878;
  border-radius: 375px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
}
```

You can use `top` and `left` properties to re-position as per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

So many solutions. but this one worked best

Please **Set position to absolute** on the pseudo element and remove margin. My solution uses positioning to get wrapped lines automatically line up correctly.

**Advantages:**

- very compact code
- works with any font size 
  (no absolute pixel values contained)
- aligns rows perfectly 
  (no slight shift between first line and following lines)

```css
.container {
  width:170px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  list-style-type: none;
  position:relative;
  word-break: break-all;
}
 li::before {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #00c878;
  border-radius: 375px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list unordered">
        <h3 class="text-grey-150 h5 "> Branchen ETFs </h3>
        <ul class="">
            <li>Technologie ETF
                <br>
            </li>
            <li style="/* word-break: break-all; */">Finanzdienstleistungen ETF</li>
            <li>Gesundheitswesen ETF
                <br>
            </li>
            <li>Immobilien ETF
                <br>
            </li>
            <li>Industrie ETF</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```